# Size classes terminology issue

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6, size-classes

When I change to wc|hAny from the bottom bar it says Base Values for all compact width layouts. And when I do wC|hR it says Final Values for all iPhones in portrait. I am confused by these Base values and Final values. What is the difference and use of these. I am having a lot of trouble with these.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is on the little green dots!

When you see various green dots lighten up, this is a **base value** that can be used for ANY size (be it height or width). When you see just one green dot over the shaded area, than it's a **final value**, as the current size class will only work for this size.

More info here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/SelectingASizeClass.html

Answer (score 0):

Size Class provide a way to adapt all kinds of devices with landscape and portrait. I give
you an example : you can design iPhone's portrait view use wC|hA, and switch to landscape use wA | hC ,  then if you want to adapt iPad , only to choose wA | hC ,and It does not affect the iPhone's composition.

Comment: But still what is the difference between Base values and Final values?

Comment: Changes you make when in the Base Values configuration apply to all devices, whereas changes you make in the Final Values configuration will only apply to iPads.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to mcatach for the reference, first of all, it's good to understand what is 'Any' - it's a mix of Compact and Regular width/height. You can see

> when you select the size class Any for either dimension, green dots in tiles indicate areas where your base value design specifications take effect for this size combination. For example, for the Any Width | Any Height combination, green dots in all of the tiles show that the layout constraints and views that you specify on the Interface Builder canvas apply to every device size and orientation.

So you can play with that, you're choosing 'Any' and tiles are highlighting in 'Compact' and 'Regular', because it's combination of them.

**And the answer is** when you're choosing **'Any'** width/height it will be **Base value** for both or one of them because it fits for 'Compact' and 'Regular'.
"When you select a **specific size class** for each dimension, a single green dot in a tile and the label **Final Values** indicate that your layout values apply **exclusively** to the shaded tiles on the grid. For example, when you select Compact Width | Regular Height, changes to layout constraints and views apply **exclusively** to iPhone devices in portrait orientation.

So '**Final**' means "**special for**" or "specific" for concrete device/ group of devices and '**Base**' fits for '**Any**' (Compact or Regular).